# Is there any way to add log files for review in gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I want to add log files for reference in the review. These files are not the actual code files which are getting updated in the repository, but are generated while testing the actual code changes.
I want to add these files into review to support the actual code changes and making it easier for the reviewers to ensure that proper testing is done for the code changes.

I dont want the log files to get merged into the repository once the review is completed.

Comment: How about attaching the log files to the ticket referencing the changes and the review?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: put the log file in an external server and add the file url in a change comment.

Comment: Or perhaps attach them to the ticket that detailed the changes that had to be implemented.